# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined for Pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, pipe

I have this pipe and this error in the title.

Probably if any values from the array being `undefined` is ok, but how to avoid this error?

```js
export class MusclePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(muscle, searchTerm: string): MuscleComponent {
    if (!muscle || !searchTerm) {
      return muscle;
    }

    return muscle.filter(
      (muscle) =>
        muscle.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it means a `name` property doesn't exist on one or more of the `muscle` objects you are iterating through.

Ideally, you want to make sure data exists. But in your case, if there is a possibility that it doesn't, the easiest (and the minimally correct) way is to use optional chaining (?.) after the key that could potentially be optional:

```
  transform(muscle: [], searchTerm: string): MuscleComponent { 
....

    return muscle.filter(muscle => 
       muscle.name?.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1); 
    }
  }
```

(note the `?` after `muscle.name`).

But since you are chainig the method calls, you could do something like this:

```
    return muscle.filter(muscle => {
       muscle.name && searchTerm
         ? muscle.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
         : 'alternative return value';
       }
    }
```

Here we are using the ternary operator (if..else) to explicitly check for the value and return an alternative value. I also added the check for the `searchTerm` is it may potentially be undefined too:

`muscle.name && searchTerm`

Answer (score 0):

You should also include a check in case the muscle doesn't have the `name` property defined correctly as it appears this is the error you have.

```
export class MusclePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(muscle, searchTerm: string): MuscleComponent {
    if (!muscle || !muscle.name || !searchTerm) {
      return muscle;
    }

    return muscle.filter(
      (muscle) =>
        muscle.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a null/undefined check in your pipe to check if the string is null before calling `.toLowerCase`

```
if (str === undefined) return [];
```